# How do I read a file from deployment's pods using fabric8 kubernetes java client?

Tags: java, kubernetes, kubectl, fabric8, kubernetes-deployment

How can I read a file from a deployment's pods? More specifically, I want fabric8's kubernetes java client equivalent of the following command:

```sh
kubectl exec --stdin --tty deployment/otel-collector -n logcollection -- cat /otel-output/json-out.json
```

PS: you can ignore the `--stdin` and `--tty` flags.

Answer (score 0):

It's fairly simple, to read file from a `Pod` you can use the following syntax (see also [fabric8 documentation](https://github.com/fabric8io/kubernetes-client/blob/master/doc/CHEATSHEET.md)):

```
try (InputStream is = client.pods().inNamespace(currentNamespace).withName(pod1.getMetadata().getName()).file("/msg").read())  {
  String result = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is)).lines().collect(Collectors.joining("\n"));
}
```

Comment: I want to know if I can do it without pod name. I am trying to get the files with just the deployment.

Comment: Well, it could be difficult to achieve as one deployment may manage larger set of pods, so in such case in which of those pods do you want to `cat` your file ?